# How do you say "[amount of time] later"?

Tags: translation

What is the general rule for saying, for example, "2 hours later"?

Comment: Should be: [二時間後]{にじかんご}

Comment: I agree, but any particular reason you added this as a comment and not an answer?

Comment: @NattyBumppo It is too short. The system won't let me submit as an answer.

Comment: @fefe Just pad the answer with extra explanation

Comment: See also http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/4549/how-to-express-vague-amounts-of-time/4551#4551

Answer (score 7):

As fefe wrote, you add the portion of time + 後
or you can write 後 + the portion of time.

```
二時間後: 2 hours later (it is then read にじかんご)
後二時間: 2 hours "left" (it is here read あとにじかん)
一ヶ月後
一年後
etc
```

Answer (score 0):

> 二週間後　（～～後（あと）or（ご））

Just substitute ~~ with any unit of time.

---

Example:

> 四年後