# How to express vague amounts of time?

Tags: time

I'm having trouble figuring out how to express vague amounts of time in Japanese, such as `some number of months` or `some number of hours`.

I want to use this in a context where the specific number is neither important nor known, but the factor of time passing/occurring is important. For example:

> `Some hours` later, he finished the test.
>
> Traveling to and staying in another country requires `some number of months` free.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Two constructions spring to mind here.

数{すう} can be used in place of a specific number, followed by a counter, to mean "some" / "a few" / "several" (it doesn't really make a distinction in this respect...).

> 数時間後、彼は試験を終わった。

This can be used in ways you might not expect:

> 数十秒 some tens of seconds
>   十数秒 ten-(and-some)-odd seconds (between 10 and 19)
>   二十数年 twenty-(and-some)-odd years

Alternatively, you can use 何 + counter + か.

> 他の国に滞在するなら、[何ヶ月]{なんかげつ}かは開いておかなければなりません。

The same kind of uses seen above for 数 also apply to 何.

Comment: (I'm hoping I haven't made mistakes elsewhere in those sentences...)

Comment: `a few` (2 to 3) and `several` (more than that) make distinction. Usually, `数` only means `a few`, not `several`.

Comment: there's also も like 何回も

Comment: Shouldn't it be '試験を終えた'or'終わらせた'...? 終わる is an intransitive verb and 終える is a transitive verb, no?

Comment: @Chocolate: I believe 終わる is used transitively as well (though perhaps 終える is more strictly correct?). [Sense 4 on Daijirin](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?enc=UTF-8&p=%E7%B5%82%E3%82%8F%E3%82%8B&dtype=0&dname=0ss&stype=0).

Comment: @sawa: Then what word or expression would you use for "several"?

Answer (score 10):

I think Hyperworm already did a good job of answering the question, so I'll just focus on saying "later"/"before".

Adding `前{まえ}` or `後{ご}` after any of these to mean "a few ... ago" or "after a few ...", e.g. `数{すう}分{ふん}前{まえ}` "a few minutes ago" or `数{すう}分{ふん}後{ご}` "after a few minutes":

- `数{すう}秒{びょう}`: "a few seconds"
- `数{すう}分{ふん}`: "a few minutes"
- `数{すう}時{じ}間{かん}`: "a few hours"
- `数{すう}日{じつ}`: "a few days"
- `数{すう}週{しゅう}間{かん}`: "a few weeks"
- `数{すう}[ヶ]{か}月{げつ}`: "a few months"
- `数{すう}[年]{ねん}`: "a few years"

I don't think you can say `数{すう}時{じ}（後/前）`. I'm not sure whether `数{すう}月{げつ}（後/前）` or `数{すう}週{しゅう}（後/前）` are valid or not, but `数ヶ月（後/前）` and `数週間（後/前）` seem to be much more commonly used.